# How to remove brakets on Json respone

Tags: json, laravel, api, response, laravel-passport

im working on Laravel Rest Api with passeport ,
in return response()->json()  i want to trim the brackets

I've tried trim($json,'[]') function but it's not what i want

```
public function getOffers()
    {
        $offers = Offer::where('type', 'primary')->where('active', 1)->get();
        $paks = Offer::where('type', 'pack')->where('active', 1)->get();
        return response()->json([
            'offersList' => $offers,
            'packsList' => $paks,
        ], 200);

    }
```

i expect the output will be

```
{
    "offersList": {
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Gold",
            "description": null
        }
    },
    "packsList":[]
}
```

but the actual result  is

```
{
    "offersList": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Gold",
            "description": null
        }
    ],
    "packsList":[]
}
```

Comment: Why do you not want the [] brackets? They are the right notation for what you are doing here.

Comment: FYI, your "expected" output is invalid. `Expecting 'STRING', '}', got '{'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$offers` is a collection, and thus an array in JSON.

If `$offers` should be a single item, use `first()` instead of `get()` and it will be rendered as a single object in your JSON instead of an array of objects.

```
$offers = Offer::where('type', 'primary')->where('active', 1)->first();
```

If `$offers` should, at times, contain *multiple* offers, leave it as-is; it's correct!

Answer (score 2):

Braces `{}` nested in another object is not valid JSON.

Objects can be used in property values and as array elements.

Not valid JSON

```
{
  "offersList": {
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Gold",
      "description": null
    }
  }
}
```

Valid option 1

```
{
  "offersList": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Gold",
      "description": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Valid option 2

```
{
  "offersList": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Gold",
    "description": null
  }
}
```

You can use online linters to quickly validate your JSON structure.
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/